# Are there neural networks with very few nodes that decently solve non-trivial problems?

Tags: neural-networks

I'm interested in knowing whether there exist any neural network, that solves (with  >=80% accuracy) any nontrivial problem, that uses very few nodes (where 20 nodes is not a hard limit). I want to develop an intuition on sizes of neural networks.

Comment: Universal approximation theorem: a neural network with one hidden layer can approximate any "reasonable" function given a sufficient number of nodes in the hidden layer.

Comment: I think it will not be easy to answer your question. What do you mean by "non-trivial problem"?

Comment: I want few nodes even in hidden layers.

Comment: @nbro my sense of "non-trivial" in this context is intractable or unsolved.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Even if it’s impossible to answer this question properly, as *non trivial* is not well defined (maybe the author will edit this questions later, to specify it better), I take the opportunity to point out this paper which looks interesting to me

[Smallest Neural Network to Learn the Ising Criticality](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.02171)

Assuming you have a general idea of the [Ising Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model) I think the problem of identifying the critical temperature from a data driven perspective can be considered as *non trivial* and the paper shows how the authors have improved the performance related to solve this task with NN passing from 100 Hidden Neurons, as performed in this paper [Machine learning phases of matter](https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys4035) from 2017, to only 2 Hidden Neurons

Just my cents:

- reducing the neurons, while keeping good performance, should help in terms of **neural processing interpretability** which is notoriously obscure and its complexity grows (exponentially) with the number of neurons

Comment: I just wanted examples that the community itself found interesting. I think it is actually non trivial to define non triviality. Right?

Comment: @GuillermoMosse No, it's quite trivial to define non-trivial. The definition is more or less arbitrary depending on what best fits the situation. I'm sure a very simple NN could learn to tell whether or not a given number is a non-trivial square root...